# Какие фреймворки использовать для работы с VK API в C#?

Tags: c#, vkontakte-api

Как можно работать с VK API в C#?

Посоветуйте фреймворки для работы с VK API в C#'е.

Comment: я пользуюсь VkNet https://vknet.github.io/vk/

Comment: У меня он не работает. Подключаю дистрибутивы с помощью using, но многие методы и классы не работают.

Answer (score 0):

Можешь использовать готовую библиотеку под названием [vk.net](https://vknet.github.io/vk/)

Comment: У меня он не работает. Подключаю дистрибутивы с помощью using, но многие методы и классы не работают.